# Netty Client/Server be made aware about channel break within ms

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty

I have a netty server in my application and netty client is one of the microservices. For health check of this particular micro service, Netty client(Microservice) establishes connection with my application and create a Netty channel. There is minor exchange of metadata when the channel is first connected and after that occasionally some data exchange. Channel help us identify the uptime of Microservice constantly.

Problem we are facing is:
a. What happens if there is power outage on the server. How quickly will my client come to know. I want this in the order of ms and how?
b. What happens if I pull out LAN cable on the server. I want client to be made aware within ms and how do we approach this?

Generally we expect that server will go down and channel will be disconnected and client will come to know, however client gets to know much later leading to lot of issues in terms of uptime and connectivity.

Is there any way by which my netty client be made aware of these 2 disconnects within ms ?

Same is applicable for server as well. i.e. if the same activity is done on client end and server has to know instantly.

P.S. I cannot do ping pong between Netty Client and Netty Server

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are infeasible without application level support. This is because of the nature of design of TCP itself.

The nature of a forced disconnect by either pulling the LAN cable, or a power outage means no packets are send over the network by this event, so this cannot be used to detect this

While there is a TCP length 0 packet, end points are not required to respond with ACK to those packets, so this can also not be relied on. (And even if its supported, you still have to maintain a proper timeout system to protect against short term packet loss (that is not harmful for the long term ))

Your best bet overall would still be sending those raw zero length packets (not sure how to do this using Netty), and if you are in luck, hoping 1 of the routers on the route returns a "ICMP Destination not reachable", and building a retry system inside your protocol.